# Error when typing "npm start" in visual studio using react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, npm

```
PS C:\Users\PC1\Downloads\portfolio_website-STARTER> npm start

> portfolio_website-starter@1.0.0 start C:\Users\PC1\Downloads\portfolio_website-STARTER
> node index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PC1\Downloads\portfolio_website-STARTER\index.js'  
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio_website-starter@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio_website-starter@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-05T22_40_19_833Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\PC1\Downloads\portfolio_website-STARTER>
```

The error shown above happens when I try to run `npm start` to start the virtual host.

I have tried the following:

1. Updated node.js to the latest version.
2. Went to *package.json* under `scripts` and added `"start": "node index.js"`.

Comment: Do you have this file it complains about: **C:\Users\PC1\Downloads\portfolio_website-STARTER\index.js** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, do you install the dependencies? (npm i)
Then, exists index.js file in the portfolio_website-STARTER folder?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Yes, I didn't install the dependencies, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your startup file is index.js in your package.json file and make sure you have index.js in your project.